# How to access env variables from react, e.g. for an API key?

Tags: reactjs

I want to store an API key using my `.bashrc` and then access it in my react application so that is is not stored within the application.

my .bashrc has `export EXPO_YELP_API_KEY = 'jfdkfjdfkdjfkd...'`

Within my app, I am trying to replace

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer rSza8...' }y.
});
// which works fine but exposes the key, with:

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + process.env.EXPO_YELP_API_KEY }
});
```

However, I get unauthorized, and when I try to log `process.env.EXPO_YELP_API_KEY` I get `undefined`

Note: Not using create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

If you are using create-react-app, you may prefix that environment variable with `REACT_APP_`.

Using this, your environment variable will be embedded during build time which means anyone could inspect your app's files and read it. For this reason, it is only recommended for public environment variables, not for private ones (ex: private API key).

Follow this link for more detail: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/